# Cambiar color fondo de div. React

Tags: reactjs, usestate

tengo la siguiente situacion. Estoy mapeando un lista de nombres, y cada nombre esta en un div. Quiero que al hacer click en algun div, este cambie de color como "seleccionado" pero si hago click en otro div, este vuelva a su color original y se cambie el color del nuevo seleccionado.

He probado usando useState, pero solo he logrado que se marquen todos del mismo color seleccionado.

```js
  let arreglo =["Alex","Victor","Juan","Pablo","Fernando","Esteban"]

const seleccionado = (e) =>{
   
 e.target.className ="h-32 w-32 border-4 bg-red-700 "
  }

{arreglo.map((nombres, index) => (

            <div
              key={index}
              onClick={(e) => {
                seleccionado(e)}}
              className={"h-32 w-32 border-4 bg-blue-300"}
            >
              {nombres}
            </div>
          ))}
```

Al marcar uno cambia a color rojo, pero si marco otro, también se pone rojo. He intentado varias cosas pero no logro "desactivar" el color al original.

Answer (score 0):

Se utiliza la función para seleccionar un elemento y guardarlo al estate luego lo comparas con el className, bueno espero esto sea lo que necesites

```
export default function App() {

 const [data, setData] = useState("");

  let arreglo = ["Alex", "Victor", "Juan", "Pablo", "Fernando", "Esteban"];
 
  const seleccionado = (nombres) => {
    setData(nombres);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {arreglo.map((nombres, i) => (
        <div
          style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
          key={i}
          onClick={(e) => seleccionado(nombres)}
          className={data === nombres ? "color" : ""}
        >
          {nombres}
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estimado Ralexhx.

Tengo esta solución para ti, espero sea de ayuda.

Te explico un poco el código:

- Utilizo una variable para manejar  el elemento seleccionado al presionar sobre el.
- En la función que se encarga de capturar el evento `onClick` del `div` asigno el valor contenido en `innerHTML` a la variable `selected`
- Al final solo queda agregar dinamicamente la clase al div para que le ponga el color que desees.

Te dejo por aca el playground para que lo pruebes:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-pzle5r?file=App.tsx

```js
export default function App() {
      const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState('');
    
      let arreglo = ['Alex', 'Victor', 'Juan', 'Pablo', 'Fernando', 'Esteban'];
    
      const seleccionado = (e) => {
        setSelected(e.target.innerHTML);
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          {arreglo.map((item, index) => (
            <div
              key={index}
              onClick={seleccionado}
              className={`item ${selected === item ? 'selected' : ''}`}
            >
              {item}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

```css
h1,
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.item {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.selected {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```